# Collect hundreds of json files from url and combine into one json file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, cors

I am trying to 1) retrieve hundreds of separate json files from this website https://bioguide.congress.gov/ that contains legislators in the U.S., 2) process them and 3) combine them into a big json that contains all the individual records.

Some of the files I am working with (each individual legislator has a different url that contains their data in a json file format) can be found in these urls:

```
https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000061.json
https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000062.json
https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000063.json
https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000064.json
https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000091.json
https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000092.json
```

My approach is to create a for loop to loop over the different ids and combine all the records in an array of objects. Unfortunately, I am stuck trying to access the data.

So far, I have tried the following methods but I am getting a CORS error.

Using fetch:

```
url = "https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000061.json"

fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.text())
    .then((text) => {
      console.log(text);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Using the no-cors mode in fetch and getting an empty response:

```
url = "https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000061.json"

const data = await fetch(url, { mode: "no-cors" })
```

Using d3:

```
url = "https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F000061.json"

const data = d3.json(url);
```

I am getting a CORS related error `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` with all of them.

I would appreciate any suggestions and advice to work around this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from what @code says in their answer, here's a contrived (but tested) NodeJS example that gets the range of data (60-69) from the server once a second, and compiles it into one JSON file.

```js
import express from 'express';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import { writeFile } from 'fs/promises';

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

let dataset;
let dataLoadComplete;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});


function getData() {

  return new Promise((res, rej) => {

    // Initialise the data array
    let arr = [];

    dataLoadComplete = false;

    // Initialise the page number
    async function loop(page = 0) {

      try {

        // Use the incremented page number in the url 
        const uri = `https://bioguide.congress.gov/search/bio/F00006${page}.json`;

        // Get the data, parse it, and add it to the
        // array we set up to capture all of the data
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const data = await response.json();
        arr = [ ...arr, data];

        console.log(`Loading page: ${page}`);

        // Call the function again to get the next
        // set of data if we've not reached the end of the range,
        // or return the finalised data in the promise response 
        if (page < 10) {
          setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++page);
        } else {
          console.log('API calls complete');
          res(arr);
        }

      } catch (err) {
        rej(err);
      }

    }

    loop();

  });

}

// Call the looping function and, once complete,
// write the JSON to a file
async function main() {
  const completed = await getData();
  dataset = completed;
  dataLoadComplete = true;
  writeFile('data.json', JSON.stringify(dataset, null, 2), 'utf8');
}

main();
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't want to make the code "runnable" or it will create misleading errors since it runs on the client side.

Comment: I did explain this was a nodeJS script, not client-side. @code

Comment: Yeah, I was just suggesting that you wouldn't make it runnable to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why do you need an Express server?

Comment: I was wondering if that was important. Also, it's not my question.

Comment: You said "you must send a request from the server-side (such as PHP, Node, Python, etc).": I provided an answer based on your answer.

Comment: Okay, that's fine. I didn't mean to create any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're getting a `CORS` (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error because the website you're sending an AJAX request to (bioguide.congress.gov) has not explicitly enabled `CORS`, which means that you can't send AJAX requests (client-side) to that website because of security reasons.

If you want to send a request to that site, you must send a request from the server-side (such as PHP, Node, Python, etc).

[More on the subject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)